# bxslider: half my images are not showing

Tags: javascript, bxslider

I would love some assistance. I am a complete newbie when it comes to javascript.  I am working on my first project as a uni assignment.  I have successfully implemented the pagepiling plug in, and the bxslider is working well except for two problems.

My main problem is that I have 10 images and only five of them are showing.  If I reorder the images in the html it is always the last five that don't work.  I think this means it's a problem with the javascript but I can't see where.

The second problem occurs on the portrait oriented photos.  I have set a slideWidth: 600 which works great on landscape but leaves a white space to the right on portrait.

http://www.helencrolls.com

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 600
        });
    });
</script>

<ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="images/game-bottle-tower.jpg" title="Bottle Tower Game"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/activity-campfire.jpg" title="Annual Sleepover Campfire"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/games-frog-in-the-pond.jpg" title="Playing Frog in the Pond"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/craft-balsa-planes.jpg" title="Making Balsa Wood Airplanes"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/craft-south-america.jpg" title="South American Bird Masks"/></li>
    <li><img src="cooking-chocolate-crackles.jpg" title="Making Chocolate Crackles"/></li>
    <li><img src="outdoors-childrens-garden.jpg" title="A Visit to the Children's Garden"/></li>
    <li><img src="outings-kite-day.jpg" title="Region Kite Day"/></li>
    <li><img src="games-billy-cart.jpg" title="Billy Carts at Eltham North"/></li>
    <li><img src="activities-totally-wild.jpg" title="A Walk on the Wild Side"/></li>
    <li><img src="games-duck-duck-goose.jpg" title="Joey Joey Scout (also known as Duck Duck Goose)"/></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These images are all stored in your images folder on your web site. However, you are not pointing them all to your images directory.

```
<img src="games-duck-duck-goose.jpg">
```

should be

```
<img src="images/games-duck-duck-goose.jpg">
```